# How to make a package for buttons

Tags: packages

I am trying to make a `Package` for a piece of  code though it's not needed here as it is very small. But my actual code here is a little bit different from that code. When I tried to make a package for  `Button`. I found that the symbol `True` is protected.

I have made a package with the function `Buttonfun`

```
 BeginPackage["package`"]
 Buttonfun[g1_,g2_]:= Button["     ",(g1=!g1;),Background->g2,Appearance->          
                     "Frameless",Method-> "Queued"];
 EndPackage[]
```

but when I call this with

```
  Buttonfun[q1,Orange]
```

from my notebook, it is showing error message symbol `True` is protected.

Comment: Is `q2` defined?

Comment: @cormullion: yes, I have edited in question.

Comment: Your code works for me when `q2` is defined.

Comment: @cormullion: How are you making functions in package for buttons?

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question to show us the steps you took and where the problems occurred.

Comment: @cormullion: I have edited.

Comment: I added two commas after two `Spacer` commands where you forgot them. These errors yielded the multiplication of a `Spacer` and a `Text` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: As I understand it now, the first (large) block of code isn't really necessary to understand your problem, nor is it actually a package problem. Only the Buttonfun definition and call are necessary. If you agree, you could cut your question down to these essentials.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I actually wanted to tell that after making package also, the code should work in the same way as it was working before making package.

Comment: What I mean is that the error isnt related to the package part. You would get the same if you used the definition only. The solution would be the same too. That would reduce your question to two lines of code, one error message and a sentence containing the message instead of more than a full page.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, I got it and edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prevent `q1` from being immediately evaluated when you use it in `Buttonfun[q1,Orange]`, otherwise `Buttonfun` will try to make the assigment `True = !True` which causes the error. To do this you have to tell `Buttonfun` to "hold" its first argument, so it can make the assigment to the *symbol* `q1` instead of the *value* `True`.

The code to tell `Buttonfun` to hold its first argument is:

```
SetAttributes[Buttonfun,HoldFirst]
```